# How do I combine a salt and hash for John The Ripper?

Tags: hash, salt, john-the-ripper

I found a password hash 
`*61A2BD98DAD2A09749B6FC77A9578609D32518DD`

I found a salt somewhere else.

How do I combine these to feed into John the Ripper?

When I run John on the hash (minus the *) John seems to think it is "sha-160" or maybe "Raw-SHA1".

Comment: This is in the documentation, actually

Comment: And multiple online tutorials: https://www.openwall.com/lists/john-users/2010/10/05/1 and http://pentestmonkey.net/cheat-sheet/john-the-ripper-hash-formats